# Web Project and Hibernate Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I am running a web application that uses Hibernate for data persistence.

Now I have created another webproject and included necessary jar files etc.
While fetching data I got an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:177)
    at com.core.dao.OpenIncidentDao.getAllOpenIncidents(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1405)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1427)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1414)
    ... 5 more
```

My other web project is running fine. Also **`hibernate.cfg.xml`** is in its place.
**`hibernate.cfg.xml`** is under EarContent/hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: is hibernate.cfg.xml in `WEB-INF/`

Comment: hibernate.cfg.xml is under EarContent/hibernate.cfg.xml.  Both the web projects and hibernate project are added in EAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in calling my hibernate class. I was not calling it from a jsp page. Doing so problem solved.

Before this I was calling it from a java class main method to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Classpath issue. Check to see which is your project root folder.

Comment: Both the web projects and hibernate project are added in EAR.

Comment: Then this is a ClassLoader issue. Which app server are you using?

Comment: All my hibernate classes are accessible. Problem comes when it tries to make session. Appserver: JBoss.

Comment: Just make sure hibernate.cfg.xml will eventually be deployed in WEB-INF/classes.